# laravel scheduling not working in windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scheduler

I am working on laravel scheduling everything is working fine. My schedule code is below:

```php
public function handle()
{
    //
    $words = [
        'aberration' => 'a state or condition markedly different from the norm',
        'convivial' => 'occupied with or fond of the pleasures of good company',
        'diaphanous' => 'so thin as to transmit light',
        'elegy' => 'a mournful poem; a lament for the dead',
        'ostensible' => 'appearing as such but not necessarily so'
    ];
    $key = array_rand($words);
    $value = $words[$key];
    $word = new Word;
    $word->word_key = $key;
    $word->word_value = $value;
    $word->save();
    $this->info('Word of the Day saved in table');
}

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('word:day')->everyMinute();
}
```

Now after that, I run the command the **PHP artisan schedule: run** it's saving the data in word table.

Now my question is that after one minute it's not saving again... I have researched on google and try many references it's not working at all.

My project is in E Drive path is **E:/xammp/htdocs/testtutorials/phpmonitor** and I run below command and it's not working

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
  ----------------------------------------------------------
* * * * * php /E:/xammp/htdocs/testtutorials/phpmonitor/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

its giving me below error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command you have above is a UNIX-style command. Windows is different in the following aspects:

1. Paths do not start with a `/`, they start with a drive letter.
2. The `/dev/null` device does not exist. The Windows equivalent is `nul`.

So, change your command to the following:

```
php E:\xampp\htdocs\testtutorials\phpmonitor\artisan schedule:run >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: command seems to be working fine but its not saving data in databbase after one minute?

Comment: this is same as php artisan schedule:run

Comment: its saving data only when i run command i want to save after everyminute without running the command

Comment: You're supposed to put the above command into the task scheduler (on Windows), or the crontab (on UNIX-like systems), not run it manually (though you can run manually to test). The framework itself will not handle the repeated runs for you.

Comment: so what about cpanel i will add command in cron jobs section in cpanel so after that where i found Task scheduler? really confusing can you elaborate?